# Recursive funtion call in python

Tags: python, function, recursion, dynamic-programming, nonetype

[SS of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMWw.png) 
I tried to solve the 0-1 knapsack problem in python but when I call the function inside the function it shows that int type and None type can't add together. It is happening because python by default returns any function as none type. Is there any other option I can try.
Thanks for reading

```
def knapsack(w, v, n, cap):
    if (n == 0) or (cap == 0):
        return 0

    if w[n-1] > cap:
        return knapsack(w, v, n-1, cap)

    elif w[n-1] <= cap:
        return max(v[n-1] + knapsack(w, v, n-1, cap-w[n-1]), knapsack(w, v, n-1, cap)) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = list(map(int, input().split()))
    v = list(map(int, input().split()))
    cap = 7
    n = len(w)
    max_profit = knapsack(w, v, n, cap)
    print(max_profit)
```

Comment: What will `knapsack` return if `w[n-1] == cap`?

Comment: In python function body should be separated from the rest of your code by intendation (1 tab or 4 spaces). Your function body has currently no intendation, so it is considered as regular code and function us literally empty. Try intending your dunction and it should work!

Comment: @MilTy It's my mistake while asking here, It is properly intended in actual function

Comment: @enzo thanks man I just changed < to <= and it worked but I still can't get what was the problem

Comment: @AkshatBansal there was a case when function finished without return statement. It happened when none of 3 conditions is True. Literally, when: (n != 0) and (cap != 0) and (w[n-1] == cap).

Comment: @AkshatBansal when none of the conditions are true, it'll return nothing which is considered as none-type.

Comment: Google is your friend https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/

Comment: Thank you guys for explaining this, I never thought someone would answer such a lame question